# How to concatenate the echo to the variable?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I have a *variable*  named `$query` and an array `explode[0]`.The array returns a string which works perfectly fine but the only problem is i want the `;` at the end of the string.

```
$query =  $explode[0].echo ';';
```

Which is not working.

Comment: Why not `$query =  $explode[0].';'`

Comment: @Zhorov thanks a lot man i know its really a silly doubt but i thought that it must be echoed in  order to get it printed.